# Keras Custom method has y_pred shape different from output of model

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I am working on custom loss function and the y_pred I got has shape is different from what is output in the summary

```
conv2d_100 (Conv2D)             (None, 3, 360, 512)  85          leaky_re_lu_27[0][0]             
==================================================================================================
Total params: 4,128,849
Trainable params: 4,119,761
Non-trainable params: 9,088
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

This the output I got:

```
Defining loss function
y_true [None, None, None]
y_pred [None, 3, None, 512]
```

The code is this:

```
def focal_loss(content, label_remap, gamma_=2, w_d=1e-4):
    def focal_loss_fixed(y_true, y_pred):
        num_classes = len(content.keys())
        print("y_true_b", y_true.get_shape().as_list())

        cv_eqation = K.constant([0.114, 0.587, 0.299])
        y_true = tf.multiply(y_true, cv_eqation)
        y_true = tf.reduce_sum(y_true, axis=3)
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.uint8)

        print("Defining loss function")
        print("y_true", y_true.get_shape().as_list())
        print("y_pred", y_pred.get_shape().as_list())
        .
        .
        return loss
return focal_loss_fixed
```

So, why I have **None** instead of the high of the output?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46667294/revisions) to get the right shape you should use

```
K.int_shape(y_pred)
```